# Error with lambda function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a data frame `sp` with a column named `Status`. The values in the `Status` column are either `'Done'` or `'Waiting'`. I need to change the values of the `Status` column using a lambda function, where a status of `'Done'` is changed to `'A'` and a status of `'Waiting'` is changed to `'N'`. This is how I tried to do it:

```
sp['Status'] = sp['Status'].apply(lambda x: x='A' if x=='Done' else x='N')
```

I then get the following error message:

```
sp['Status'] = sp['Status'].apply(lambda x: x='A' if x=='Done' else x='N')
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your code. Please do post the **actual** error so as not to confuse answerers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use assignment (a statement) inside a lambda (which only takes expressions).

The lambda should instead just *return* the new value:

```
sp['Status'] = sp['Status'].apply(lambda x: 'A' if x == 'Alive' else 'N')
```

The result of the expression in a `lambda` is always the return value.

Note that you just use [`Series.map()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) here instead:

```
sp['Status'] = sp['Status'].map({'Alive': 'A', 'Waiting': 'N'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the lambda syntax as if there was a `return` in front. And you cannot make assignments in the lambda body:

`sp['Status'] = sp['Status'].apply(lambda x: 'A' if x=='Done' else 'N')`